# Can you make an update to an iOS app before it has been released?

Tags: ios, app-store

Say I have a release date of Sept. 1. This is a hard date and the app HAS to be in the app store by then. So I submit the app now just to be safe. It gets approved but I want to add more features. Can I make updates even though the app hasn't been released yet?

Comment: What do you mean by "not released yet"? When it gets approved, it will be instantly in AppStore.

Comment: What?  Is there something stopping you from writing code while you wait for your app to be approved?

Comment: Aren't you given the option to set a future release date?

Comment: @H2CO3 Not necessarily. When you submit an app for review, you can either have the app released as soon as it's approved, or you can set a release date, or you can have the app held until you decide to release it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding has always been that you can only have one pending version of an app at a time -- if your app gets approved but you decide to update it before you release the approved version, you have to first reject the approved version and then submit the update for review. Once you make your app available, you can then submit another version.

Don't take my word for it, though -- get what you can from the section on updating in the [iTunesConnect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), and contact Apple for clarification if you need to.

Comment: Thanks. There isn't any info about this particular issue in the Dev Guide. Contacting Apple is akin to contacting someone in another solar system so I'll take your work for it.

Comment: There's a line in there that says: *Once your first version is approved and available on the App Store, you can add another minor version directly from the Manage Your Applications page...* That's a little vague, perhaps, but it mainly agrees with what I wrote. On the other point: I've always found the Apple Developer Relations folks to be as helpful as they're allowed to be. Some things they just can't tell you, like when your app will be approved or why it was rejected. But on questions like this one they've often gone out of their way to help me understand the process.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, but that would mean having a way to manage your code (via git or any code tracking system) so that each update code is tracked (if you want to go back to the first release to check out the code and then jump back to the "updated" to fix the code).

My first project was not code tracked. I had to create different folders with the code changes. And it turned into a mess.

Also remember to change the version in the info plist if you want to make binaries and test them via itunes (this is how the "updates" work) or send the final work to apple.

Comment: The OP is asking about having multiple unreleased versions in the app store review process at once. It's not a question about version control systems.